# Constructing character table of subgroup from character table of whole group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

If $\psi : G \to \mathbb C$ is a character and $U \le G$, then $\psi_{|U} : U \to \mathbb C$ is a character, but I guess this might not be irreducible with respect to $U$. But is it possible to construct the character table of $U$ from the character table of $G$?

Comment: This is hard in general. E.g. every group $G$ is a subgroup of some symmetric group $S_n$, and the character table of $S_n$ is in some sense known, but $G$'s might still be hard. In particular the character table of $S_n$ consists of integers but the character table of $G$ need not.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But it is possible in principle? Are their known constructions?

Comment: Some stuff is known if $U$ is normal. The keyword to look up is Clifford theory. If $U$ is not normal then I don't know.